# Build MongoDB filter expression from field expression: `Expression<Func<T, string>>` to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

Tags: c#, mongodb, lambda, expression

I am writing a generic service that for a `T` should find a record in a mongodb database based on the supplied id field `Expression<Func<T, string>>`.

The model look something like this:

```
struct TestEntity{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

the service looks something like this:

```
class Repository<T> {
    private readonly Expression<Func<T, string>> _idField;
    private readonly IMongoCollection<T> _collection;

    public Repository(Expression<Func<T, string>> idField, IMongoCollection<T> collection)
    {
        _idField= idField;
        _collection = collection;
    }

    public T Find(string id) {
        Func<T, string> idAccessor = _idField.Compile();
        FilterDefinition<T> filter = new ExpressionFilterDefinition<T>(
            // the mongodb filter takes an Expression<Func<T, bool>>
            entity => idAccessor(entity) == id);
        return _collection.Find(filter).First();
    }
}
```

However, mongodb seems to not be able to properly handle that expression. I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Invoke(value(System.Func`2[TestEntity,System.String]), {document}) is not supported.

I suspect I cannot compile the id expression to a function and just use that to build another expression. If that is true, then my question is how would I turn the `Expression<Func<T, string>>` into an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by manually taking the expression apart and reassembling it. basically, construct a new lambda expression with the same parameter, but wrap the body in `Expression.Equal()`, like this:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(_idField.Body, Expression.Constant(id)),
    _idField.Parameters.First());
```